# CSS columns that stacks on resize using only floats

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I am trying to achieve this using just floats:

```
|A******* B******************|
|*300px * * auto            *|
|*      * *                 *|
|******** *******************|

|A*******     |
|*300px *     |
|*      *     |
|********     |
|B************|
|* auto      *|
|*           *|
|*************|
```

Block B should take remaining space and go underneath of block A when it is less than `500px` of space available for it. I tried many combinations, negative `margin` solutions, but all without success.

The problem is that css floats are able to go down (stack) when no space left, but only when `width` specified. When `width` is not specified block occupies remaining space (which is also what I need), but can't stack. And I need **both** features for block B: taking remaining space and going under A on smaller screens.

What your suggestions for doing this without media queries and other features not supported in old browsers (IE8+ and without JS)?

Starting point:

```
<div id="blockA">
    blockA
</div>
<div id="blockB">
    <p>blockB</p>
    <p id="stopper">stopper</p>
</div>

#blockA {
    border: 1px solid powderblue;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
#blockB {
    border: 1px solid khaki;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
#blockB > p#stopper {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

See solution **below**.

Comment: What is not happening? `B` not floating under `A` or what? Why don't you use some framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot  B not floating under A. I am not using bootstrap cause I want do it myself in a custom way. And I also suspect bootstrap just uses media queries.

Comment: Can you show us the CSS and HTML that you are using? Also if you are using `auto` for `B` it may be fitting in the remaining space. Also what old browsers are you talking about `IE6`?

Comment: Please show us some code (you can throw together a little sample [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to explain your issue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: container with `float: left` and blockB with `overflow: hidden`

```
.container {
    clear: left;
}
.blockA {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    float: left; 
}
.blockB {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    min-width: 500px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="blockA">blockA</div>
    <div class="blockB">blockB</div>
</div>
```

Tested in IE8 and FF, works exactly as described in my question.

Answer (score 1):

This will help:

```
#blockA {
    border: 1px solid powderblue;
    width: 100px;
    float: left; /*YOU WERE NOT FLOATING THE DIV B*/
}
```

Comment: This does not makes any sense, sorry